# Is thera any way to include special characters with Sequelize's isAlpha validate?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create some queries using Sequelize, I've made a validation rule like this:

```
validate: {
    isAlpha: {
        args: true,
        msg: 'Must be only letters'
    }
}
```

But I can't make it work with special characters like **ã**, **é** etc.
I've read the docs but couldn't find anything about special characters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved using a regular expression:

```
validate: {
    is: {
        args: /^([A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u00ff\s]*)$/g,
        msg: 'Must be only letters',
    },
}
```